# Symfony Return Form Field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I would like to create a function which returns a form field that can then be added to a form.
Currently I have something like:

```
$builder->add($name,$type,$options);
```

I would like something similar to:

```
function getField()
{
    //$name, $type, $options = blah

    $builder = $this->createFormBuilder();
    $builder->add($name,$type,$options);
    return $builder;
}

$field = getField();
$builder->add($field);
```

Comment: This would result in `$builder->add($this->createFormBuilder()->add($name, $type, $options));` which isn't going to work. You need to elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only create one `FormBuilder` per Form. Your issue could be solved by passing the FormBuilder instance to the the function that generates the field:

```
function addField($builder)
{
    //$name, $type, $options = blah

    $builder->add($name,$type,$options);
}

$builder = $this->createFormBuilder();

addField($builder);
```

Does this meet your requirements?

Comment: This certainly works, I was hoping to avoid passing in the `$builder` but as you can only have one per form it sounds like that's not possible.